# Change class of input elements inside cloned div with drag & drop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have two columns. The column on the left loads with rectangular divs, which inside of these divs are 5 input elements that are loaded via PHP with data. The user can drag a div from the left column over to the right column. This  will clone it and the user can begin to edit the input elements. I have been able to change the ID of the parent div once its cloned but am running into trouble changing the class names of the input elements inside the cloned div. Im going to save them via ajax and will build an array of all values that belong to each classname. The cloned class names must be different from the original as not to capture the original data.

This is an example of one of the divs that a user can drag and clone. No PHP yet.

```
<div class='pcaccount' draggable="true" id='account' data-id='accountid' ondragstart="drag(event)" >    
               <table  class='tablesorter'>
                    <thead id='accountrow'>
                        <th align='center'>
                            <input type='text' value='hello' class='owner' >
                        </th>
                        <th align='center'>
                            <input type='text' value='hello' class='custodian'  >
                        </th>
                        <th align='center'>
                            <input type='text' value='hello' class='type' >
                        </th>
                        <th align='center'>
                            <input type='text' value='hello' class='tax' >
                        </th>
                        <th align='center'>
                            <input type='text' value='hello' class='accvalue' >
                        </th>
                    </thead>
                </table>
            </div>
```

This is my current JS. It works fine for dragging, dropping, cloning, and changing the ID of the parent DIV but i can't seem to be able to change the class of the input elements within the div.

```
function allowDrop(ev) {
ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev) {
ev.dataTransfer.setData("div", ev.target.id);
var i = 0;
}

function drop(ev) { 
var newId = 'newaccount';
ev.preventDefault();
var data=ev.dataTransfer.getData("div");
var nodeCopy = document.getElementById(data).cloneNode(true);
nodeCopy.id = newId+i; 
nodeCopy.class = 'newaccount';
ev.target.appendChild(nodeCopy);
i++;
}
```

Iv neglected to include any code I have tried to make to accomplish this as its rubbish. Any help on this would be greatly appreciated. Also it would be necessary to change the ID of the "thead" as I want to append another table header to it once it is cloned.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you tagged the question with jQuery, here is a jQuery snippet which should allow you to modify child elements of the cloned node:

```
$('input', nodeCopy).each(function () {
    $(this).removeClass(...).addClass(...);
});

$('thead', nodeCopy).each(function () {
    $(this)[0].id = ...;
});
```

Without jQuery, you can achieve something similar using `nodeCopy.querySelector` or `nodeCopy.querySelectorAll`.

Comment: Ok this works, it is changing the class to the one i specify in addClass. However I simply want to append the original class name with 'new' not replace it. What the code above does is change all unique classes to 'new'. Thank you for your replay. Much appreciated.

Comment: I guess I can just change 'input' to the class that I want to change and do that for all of them.